# Media query issues on Samsung Mail and Gmail app on iphone

Tags: android, ios, gmail, media-queries, html-email

I'm having issues with an email template where Samsung Mail seems to ignore the media query. It just displays the desktop version. This isn't happening anywhere else when I test on EOA. For Gmail app in iPhone, it does show the mobile version, but it's not centered and there's a left margin. What am I missing?

Expected:

[image: Expected mobile version]

Samsung:

[image: Displayed in Samsung Mail]

Gmail:

[image: Displayed in Gmail]

Code Setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dtd HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/tr/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
   <xml>
      <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      <o:AllowPNG/>
      <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
      </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
   </xml>
<![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style type="text/css">
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    

<style type="text/css">
    body {width: 100% !important; min-width:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; max-width: 600px; padding: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
/* gmail fixes */
    *[class="gmail-fix"] {display: none !important;}
    .gmailfix {
       display: none !important;
    }
    
    .ii a[href] {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
    }
    h1, h2 { font-weight: inherit !important; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;}
    th { font-weight: normal !important; }
    /* /gmail fixes */
    /* IOS fixes begin */
a [x-apple-data-detectors] {
  color: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-size: inherit !important;
  font-family: inherit !important;
  font-weight: inherit !important;
  line-height: inherit !important;
}
span [x-apple-data-detectors] {
  color: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-size: inherit !important;
  font-family: inherit !important;
  font-weight: inherit !important;
  line-height: inherit !important;
}
/* /IOS fixes */
    .ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}
    .ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
    table tr td {mso-line-height-rule: exactly;}
   
        
        .c_4e4e4e { color:#4e4e4e !important;}
        .c_959594 { color:#959594 !important;}
        .c_ffffff { color:#ffffff !important;}
        .c_727272 { color:#727272 !important;}
        .c_007cab { color:#007cab !important;}
        
        /* hover */
     a.btn:focus, a.btn:hover {
                background-color: #e7e7e7 !important;
                background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 1) !important;
                color: #00aeef !important;
            }
        .hover_underline:focus, .hover_underline:hover { text-decoration: underline !important; }
        /* end hover */
  
        @media only screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
            body {
                       background-color: #ffffff !important;
                       width: auto !important;
                       }
              .wrapper {
                width: 100% !important;
            }
           
            .container_module, .fullwidth {
                width: 100% !important;
                
            }
            .content_17 { width: 17px !important;}
            .content_20 { width: 20px !important;}
            .content_36 { width: 36px !important;}
            .content_56 { width: 56px !important;}
            .content_270 { width: 270px !important;}
            
    
            .img_42, .img_42 img {
                 width: 42px !important;
                height: auto !important;}
            .img_36, .img_36 img {
                 width: 36px !important;
                height: auto !important;}
            .img_33, .img_33 img {
                 width: 33px !important;
                height: auto !important;}
            
            .text_12 {font-size: 12px !important;
            line-height: 14px !important;}
            .text_14 {font-size: 14px !important;
            line-height: 16px !important;}
            .text_18 {font-size: 18px !important;
            line-height: 20px !important;}
            .text_18_25 {font-size: 18px !important;
            line-height: 25px !important;}
            
            .padding_top_0 {
                padding-top: 0px !important;}
            .padding_top_7 {
                padding-top: 7px !important;}
            .padding_top_12 {
                padding-top: 12px !important;}
            .padding_top_15 {
                padding-top: 15px !important;}
            .padding_top_17 {
                padding-top: 17px !important;}
            .padding_top_20 {
                padding-top: 20px !important;}
            
            .padding_bottom_15 {
                padding-bottom: 15px !important;}
            .padding_bottom_17 {
                padding-bottom: 17px !important;}
            .padding_bottom_20 {
                padding-bottom: 20px !important;}
            .padding_bottom_25 {
                padding-bottom: 25px !important;}
            .padding_bottom_35 {
                padding-bottom: 35px !important;}
            .padding_bottom_45 {
                padding-bottom: 45px !important;}
            
            .padding_left_0 {padding-left: 0 !important;}
            .padding_left_17 {padding-left: 17px !important;}
            .padding_left_20 {padding-left: 20px !important;}
            .padding_left_35 {padding-left:35px !important;}
            .padding_left_45 {padding-left:45px !important;}
            
            .padding_right_0 {padding-right: 0px !important;}   
            .padding_right_20 {padding-right: 20px !important;} 
            .padding_right_25 {padding-right: 25px !important;}
            .padding_right_35 {padding-right: 35px !important;}
            .padding_right_50 {padding-right: 50px !important;}
            
            
            .display_block { display: block !important;}
            .center { text-align: center !important;}
            .show_for_mobile {display: block !important;width: auto !important;overflow: visible !important;max-height: none !important;font-size: inherit !important;line-height: inherit !important;height: auto !important;float: none !important;}
            .hide_for_mobile {display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; width: 0 !important; mso-hide: all !important; overflow: hidden !important;}
        }
</style>
</head>
    <body bgcolor="#eeeeee" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; padding: 0; margin:0; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; width:100% !important; background-color:#eeeeee; background-image:none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
<!-- Email : START -->
<!--[if (gte mso 11)|(IE)]><center>
<table role="presentation" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100%"><![endif]-->
<table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" class="container_module" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#eeeeee" align="center" style="table-layout:fixed;" ><tbody>
<tr>
<td class="container_module" width="600" valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff"> 
        
<table role="presentation" class="wrapper" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0px; mso-table-rspace: 0px;"><tbody>
        
<tr>
<td align="center" width="100%" valign="top" >
              
                
<!-- 3 Columns without CTA -->
<table role="presentation" class="container_module" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" >
                 <tbody>
<tr>
<td class="padding_left_20 padding_right_20" width="100%" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:20px; color:#00A8EA; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; padding: 0 24px 15px; margin: 0;">
<div id="threeColumnsNobtnTitle">
<h1 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:20px; color:#00A8EA; margin: 0;"><b>Lorem ipsum</b></h1>
</div>
</td>
                
</tr>
                
<tr>
<td class="padding_bottom_20 padding_right_0 padding_left_0" width="100%" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 24px 10px;">
                        
<table role="presentation" class="container_module" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" >
                            <tbody>
<tr>
                                <!-- Grey box 8 -->
                                <th class="display_block fullwidth padding_bottom_20 padding_right_0" width="33%" align="left" style="padding: 0 6px 0 0;" valign="top">
                                    
<table role="presentation" class="container_module" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" >
                       <tbody>              
<tr>
<td class="height_auto" width="100%" align="left" height="300" valign="top">
                                                
<table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" >
                                                    <tbody>
<tr>
<td class="padding_top_20 padding_right_20 padding_left_20" width="100%" align="center" valign="top" style="line-height:0px; font-size:0px; padding: 10px 9px 20px; margin: 0;"><img id="threeColumnsImg4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/280x200" alt="Image1" width="170" style="display:block; width: 100%; height: auto;"  border="0" /></td>
                                                    
</tr>
                                                    
<tr>
<td class="text_22_31 padding_right_20 padding_left_20" width="100%" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#000000; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; padding: 0 9px 10px; margin: 0;">
<div id="threeColumnsText4"><span class="text_22_31" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#000000;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam</span></div>
</td>
    
                                                
</tr>
                                                
<tr>
<td class="text_22_31 padding_right_20 padding_bottom_25 padding_left_20" width="100%" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#0041C0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; padding: 0 9px 0; margin: 0;">
<div id="box8CTA" ><a class="c_0041C0" href="http://www.linkhere.fakecom" style="color:#0041C0; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><span class="text_22_31" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#0041C0; text-decoration: none;">nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
&gt;</span></a></div>
</td>
    
                                                
</tr>
                                             
</tbody></table>
                                          </td>
                                       
</tr>
                                    
</tbody></table>
                                </th>
                                <!-- Grey box 9 -->
                                <th class="display_block fullwidth padding_bottom_20 padding_right_0 padding_left_0" width="33%" align="center" style="padding: 0 3px;" valign="top">
                                    
<table role="presentation" class="container_module" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" >
                      <tbody>               
<tr>
<td class="height_auto" width="100%" align="left" height="300" valign="top">
                                                
<table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" >
                  <tbody>                               
<tr>
<td class="padding_top_20 padding_right_20 padding_left_20" width="100%" align="center" valign="top" style="line-height:0px; font-size:0px; padding: 10px 9px 20px; margin: 0;"><img id="threeColumnsImg5" src="https://via.placeholder.com/280x200" alt="Image2" width="170" style="display:block; width: 100%; height: auto;"  border="0" /></td>
                                                    
</tr>
                                                    
<tr>
<td class="text_22_31 padding_right_20 padding_left_20" width="100%" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#000000; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; padding: 0 9px 10px; margin: 0;">
<div id="threeColumnsText5"><span class="text_22_31" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#000000;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam</span></div>
</td>
    
                                                
</tr>
                                                
<tr>
<td class="text_22_31 padding_right_20 padding_bottom_25 padding_left_20" width="100%" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#0041C0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; padding: 0 9px 0; margin: 0;">
<div id="box9CTA" ><a class="c_0041C0" href="http://www.linkhere.fakecom" style="color:#0041C0; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><span class="text_22_31" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#0041C0; text-decoration: none;">nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
&gt;</span></a></div>
</td>
    
                                                
</tr>
                                             
</tbody></table>
                                          </td>
                                       
</tr>
                                    
</tbody></table>
                                </th>
                                <!-- Grey box 10 -->
                                <th class="display_block fullwidth padding_left_0" width="33%" align="right" style="padding: 0 0 0 6px;" valign="top">
                                    
<table role="presentation" class="container_module" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#e7e7e7" >
                                        <tbody>
<tr>
<td class="height_auto" width="100%" align="left" height="300" valign="top">
                                                
<table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" >
                                        <tbody>         
<tr>
<td class="padding_top_20 padding_right_20 padding_left_20" width="100%" align="center" valign="top" style="line-height:0px; font-size:0px; padding: 10px 9px 20px; margin: 0;"><img id="threeColumnsImg6" src="https://via.placeholder.com/280x200" alt="Image3" width="170" style="display:block; width: 100%; height: auto;"  border="0" /></td>
                                                    
</tr>
                                                    
<tr>
<td class="text_22_31 padding_right_20 padding_left_20" width="100%" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#000000; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; padding: 0 9px 10px; margin: 0;">
<div id="threeColumnsText6" ><span class="text_22_31" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#000000;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam</span></div>
</td>
    
                                                
</tr>
                                                
<tr>
<td class="text_22_31 padding_right_20 padding_bottom_25 padding_left_20" width="100%" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#0041C0; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; padding: 0 9px 0; margin: 0;">
<div id="box10CTA"><a class="c_0041C0" href="http://www.linkhere.fakecom" style="color:#0041C0; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><span class="text_22_31" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#0041C0; text-decoration: none;">nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
&gt;</span></a></div>
</td>
    
                                                
</tr>
                                             
</tbody></table>
                                          </td>
                                       
</tr>
                                    
</tbody></table>
                                </th>
                            
</tr>
                        
</tbody></table>
                    </td>
                
</tr>
             
</tbody></table>
<!-- End 3 Columns without CTA -->
 
                <!-- Content ends -->
<div class="gmail-fix" style="white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; line-height:0;"> 
                           &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; &#160; </div>
                    </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
            </td>
        
</tr>
        
</tbody></table>

    <!--[if mso]></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</center><![endif]-->
<!-- Email : END -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No idea. Mostly because you only posted the header, so it makes it hard to see what the issue is with the body.

Comment: @gwally Apologies. I thought the problem would be in the header since it worked on some email clients. I added the body with a section of my code since the entire email seemed like it'd be too much. I made sure that even with that section the problem is the same on EOA.

Comment: I think there is a fundamental issue there with the reliance on media queries. See the 'hybrid' approach to support those without @media query support like Gmail IMAP (not specified here, but is still an issue for you). My tests on Samsung worked, so not sure I can give a proper answer sorry. https://www.litmus.com/blog/understanding-responsive-and-hybrid-email-design/

Comment: Same problem here. Samsung Mail v6.1.75.0 on a Samsung Galaxy S20 completely ignores media queries. 
Also I'm quite sure that (some years ago) I had some test and in fact it DID support media queries.
Tried changing doctype declaration and creating super simple media query like: `@media screeen { p {color: red !important } }` and still not working.
My guess is that if ever worked they dropped support.